# Why we can't use &(*a) but can achieve it using typedef?

Tags: c++

I'm novice at C++, and I want to understand the difference between the examples below.

We can't create function

```
void someFunc(int &*a){
    int *b=new int; //just for example
    a=b;
}
```

but using typedef

```
typedef int* pint;

void someFunc(pint &a){
    int *b=new int; //just for example
    a=b;
}
```

everything is alright.

Is it just a compiler trick, or is the reason for such behavior more complicated?

Comment: Note that `pint &a` is `int *& a`, not `int &* a`.

Comment: I was trained to read C declarations "inside-out"... start with the variable name, and read outwards. By that, int &*a reads as a pointer, to a reference, to int. Try int *&a?

Comment: @mjfgates, thanks, now I'm understand where my mistake is :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`pint& a` is equivalent to `int*& a`, not `int&* a`. You can't have a pointer-to-reference type in C++, but you can have a reference-to-pointer type.

Comment: Thanks, now I'm understand it

Answer (score 2):

It's the order of the reference and pointer. In your first example it's

```
int &*a
```

Which is a pointer to a reference which is not allowed. In the second one it's

```
int *&a
```

Which is a reference to a pointer which is allowed.